# Redirect .aspx to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, asp.net

I'm transferring an ASP.NET site to WordPress, and all my URLs are identical, except for the .aspx suffix.

Is there a one line regex htaccess solution that will forward people from

foo.com/bar/page.aspx

to

foo.com/bar/page

and

foo.com/bar.aspx

to

foo.com/bar

Answer (score 2):

No, not one-line .

Just a guess on my side here a.k.a. warning!, untested stuff ahead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite*>
# * = Your rewrite module may be named differently.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.aspx$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1
</IfModule>
```

But according to : http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite .
it might be better expressed as :

```
RedirectMatch ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1
```

Hey, wait, that's one line... Now just hope that it works... :P
If not, this might :

```
AliasMatch ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1
```

Sorry, not much of practical help at the moment, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why do a regex?

That could be easily done just by doing a replace on the end with anything ending in ".aspx"

It's simpler and the string manipulation would be must faster than a regex match.

Regex is overkill in this situation, IMO.

I just did a quick search and found this [article](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all).

Basically you could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1 [NC]
```

That should remove aspx from any url that has it.

Comment: I edited my answer with a potential rule you could make in your htaccess.